# How to property in Object Mapper with unknown server data types in Swift 4 ?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, objectmapper

I want to parse json like this:

```
let JSONString = "{\"id\":23,\"title\":\"Saramon\"}" // id is Int
let JSONString = "{\"id\":\"23\",\"title\":\"Saramon\"}". //id is String

class Category: Mappable {

    var id:Int?
    var title:String?

    //Mark - Mappable
    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
      id              <- map["id"]
      title           <- map["title"]
    }  
}
```

But when **id** is *String* in json, return nil.
So I have used of **TrasformOf** but when **id** is *Int* is show me another problem with crash.
How to fix this?

Comment: mark id as Any and check the type while using like if id is String { "id  is String" }

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two options. Either to have `TransformOf<Int, Any>` and check the type. Or create a private property of a type String, whereupon update, if value is not nil, you will set `id` with the transformed value. [This](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/713) is not the same issue as you have but it could help to solve your problem.